# Visual Studio Force Linking of Unused Libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, cl

I'm building an application that has random utility libraries in them. I for instance a staically linked SDL2, how would I go about making sure that all of its functions and symbols are included in the end result, regardless of whether or not its used?

Reworded: How can I force the VS linker to add to my final binary all symbols from statically linked libfiles? (Include SDL2.lib, end binary would have the SDL_Init symbol and whatnot.)

Comment: I don't see how thats really relevant; buried within that is hinting at the desire to be more verbose in questions and thats all you could have said had my question been to vague.

Comment: Just a wild suggestion: Have you tried the `/OPT:NOREF` linker option? I'm not sure it will work, but at a glance, it looks like what you need.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work unfortunately. It was the one I had expected to actually work.

Comment: I assume your binary is a dll - is it?   If so, do you want the dll clients to be able to use SDL2 functions that aren't exported by the dll?  Even if the linker does leave the implementations in the dll, how would they use it?

Comment: Its an EXE, but the ideal use is to build a build of LuaJIT with all sorts of libraries built in without adding the libraries to the project itself if possible.